# insert in MongoDB using php

Tags: php, mongodb, insert

```
$con = MongoDB1::connect();
$myCollection = $con->DataBase_Name->Collection_name;

$sql = array('ID' => 64444, 'LUID' => 1001, 'search_status' => 0, 'downloaded' => 1, 'user_id' => 47, 'projID' => 9, 'Leadsystem' => 1, 'Temp_date' => '2018-03-01', 'currentID' => 1001, 'Referral' => '', 'IsActive' => 0, 'dnb_status' => 0, 'download_status' => 'No', 'currently_working' => 'No');

$myCollection->insert($sql);
var_dump($sql);
```

Above is my code for inserting data in database using MongoDB. But the data is not inserting in collection. and If I am running the normal command of insertion with same data using shell the row is inserting in database. Please let me help on the same...

Comment: Post the error message/stack trace you are getting when the insert is failure thru PHP